# When I use transformer model to train a translator, why it cannot convert y to a tensor

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, transformer-model, attention-model

```
def encoder():
    input_layer = Input(batch_shape=(None, 13, 128))
    h= layer(input_layer)
    h= Masking(mask_value=0.0)(h)
    h, hidden_layer, cell_layer = LSTM(512, return_state=True)(h)
    model = Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs = [hidden_layer, cell_layer])
    return model
model=encoder()
model.summary()

class Decoder(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=max_tokens+1, output_dim=128, mask_zero=True)
        self.lstm_layer = LSTM(512,
        return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
        self.dense_layer = Dense(units=max_tokens+1)
    def call(self,inputer,hidden_layer=None,cell_layer=None):
        x=self.embedding_layer(inputer)
        if hidden_layer!=None and cell_layer!=None:
            x, h, c = self.lstm_layer(x, initial_state=[hidden_layer, cell_layer])
        else:
             x, h, c = self.lstm_layer(x)
        x=self.dense_layer(x)
        return x,h,c
        
decoder=Decoder()
for eng,germ in train.take(1):
    y,hidden,cell = decoder(germ)
@tf.function
def loss_fn(en_input, germ_input, germ_output, loss):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        enc_hidden_s, enc_cell_s = model(en_input)
        dec_output, dec_hidden_s, dec_cell_s = decoder(germ_input, enc_hidden_s,enc_cell_s)
        loss_value = loss(germ_output, dec_output)
        return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, variables)
 
def fit_german_shape(german):
    input_data = german[:,:-1]
    output_data = german[:,1:]
    return input_data,output_data
def training(train_data, test_data,optimizer, loss,epochs=5):
    batch_num=0
    batch_num2=0
    epoch_loss=0
    epoch_loss2=0
    for english,germany in train:
        germany_in,germany_out=fit_german_shape(germany)
        loss2, grad= loss_fn(english, germany_in, germany_out, loss)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad,model.trainable_variables + decoder.trainable_variables))
        epoch_loss=epoch_loss+loss2
        batch_num=batch_num+1
        avg_loss=epoch_loss/batch_num
        avg_loss3=String(avg_loss1)
        print("In this train epoch, the loss is"+ave_loss3)
    for english2,germany2 in test:
        germany_in2,germany_out2=fit_german_shape(germany2)
        hidden_state,cell_state=model(en)
        pred,temp1,temp2=decoder(germany_in2,hidden_state,cell_state)
        loss, temp3 = loss_fn(english2, germany_in2, germany_out2)
        epoch_loss2=loss+epoch_loss2
        batch_num=batch_num+1
        avg_loss2=epoch_loss2/batch_num2
        avg_loss4=String(avg_loss2)
        print("In this test epoch, the loss is"+ave_loss4)
    return avg_loss,avg_loss2
```

When I use this model to translate German to English, it report the error that "Tried to convert 'y' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported." Error may occur in the decoder to assign value to x,h,c, but I dont know why cannot convert y to a tensor.

Comment: Because you may have some null values in your input label data. Check input data for nan values.

Comment: This is a capstone from coursera and I think they do not give null values